# Why ClassFormatError: Absent Code ... rises

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jakarta-ee

I want to write some tests for my app.
App uses Spring, JPA2 (Hibernate), Tomcat 7, Java7 SE.
When I create test and try to run, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file ...
```

I found explanation
[here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract-in-class-file/).
It says that there are no method bodies. Ok seems like true...
But how my project runs when i click "Debug" in Idea? 
It compiles and runs just fine!
Here is my classpath screenshot:
http://i056.radikal.ru/1312/0c/724cabceb86a.jpg
All needed libs there, project works, but test doesn't.